# PagedViewCollection group by column, not property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, group-by

I have these 2 classes:

```
class EmpIDPayTypeSettings
{
    public Guid OID { get; set; }
    public Guid PayTypeOID { get; set; }
    public int GroupTypeID { get; set; }
    public Guid EmpOID { get; set; }
    public int OrderBy { get; set; }
}

class DocRegHour
{
    public Guid OID { get; set; }              
    public Guid DocumentOID { get; set; }    
    public Guid medarbejderOID { get; set; } 
    public Guid PaytypeOID { get; set; }     
    public string PayTypeInfo { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }  
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChangedDate { get; set; }     
}
```

I have a collection of `DocRegHour` bound to a DataGrids itemsource.
I want them grouped by `GroupTypeID`, as you can see the 2 classes have `PaytypeOID` in common.

I tried making a non-bound collapsed column with the `Header = "Group"` and set the `GroupTypeID` as text in each row.
Then I wrote:

```
var pcv = new PagedCollectionView(dataGridDayView.ItemsSource);
pcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
dataGridDayView.ItemsSource = pcv;
```

It doesn't work though. Any help?

To clarify. I have:

```
IEnumerable<DocRegHour> data;
IENumerable<EmpIDPayTypeSettings> userSettings;

var pcv = new PagedCollectionView(data);
dataGridDayView.ItemsSource = pcv;
```

Which I want to group by GroupTypeID!, which is in a different collection

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
// LINQ the stuff you need and then group by the name you give it
myData.Where(...).Select(emp => new { Group = emp.GroupTypeID });

GroupDescriptor descriptor = new GroupDescriptor("Group");
pcv.GroupDescriptors.Add(descriptor);
```

It should work. I'm not entirely sure though I understood your data-model. However I found anonymous types to be pretty handy when it comes to similar situations :)

Comment: But I don't want some kind of mutated class. I need to extract data from the rows a lot of times. Such as (SelectedItem as DocRecHour), I can not do that, with your method. Also, what if the datagrid has dynamic columns?

Comment: Ok thats understandable. Do you have NavigationProperties? If yes you can use them.

Comment: Sorry, what are those? I can't find them on msdn

Comment: A navigation property is e.g. if you have a customer that can order products. The order has a CustomerID. If you tell the Entity Framework about this relationship, it will create two navigation properties: EntityCollection<Orders> Orders on the Customer, and Customer Customer on the Order. These are very useful to make ojined linq queries without having to use join, and for grouping. But what I don't understand: How are your tables exactly related to each other?

Comment: You can join them on PaytypeOID. DocRegHour has an PaytypeOID which has a setting over in EmpIDPayTypeSettings. With your example, it would be that Order has a productID, there is also a table called productIDSettings, where each produkt can have a setting.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the [PropertyGroupDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597593%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) expects the propertyName to group items by and not the header of the column to group by.

Your class DocRegHour does not have a property named "Group", so the PagedCollectionView cannot group items by this property.

To solve this, add a property "Group" to your class or specify another property for the PropertyGroupDescriptor.